# Private variable definition inside JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, constructor, prototype

I'm learning to define 'class like' function on JavaScript using the prototype property.
When I'm defining a `People` class like so, everything is working great:

```
var People = function(firstName, lastName){
    // public
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;

    this.fullName = function(){
        console.log(full_name);
        return this;
    };

    // private
    var self = this;
    var full_name = function(){
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName;
    }();
};

var person = new People('John', 'Smith');
person.fullName();  // => "John Smith"
```

However, when I'm moving the `fullName` method outside of the initial definition like so:

```
var People = function(firstName, lastName){
    // public
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;

    // private
    var self = this;
    var full_name = function(){
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName;
    }();
};

People.prototype.fullName = function(){
    console.log(full_name);
    return this;
};

var person = new People('John', 'Smith');
person.fullName();  // => "ReferenceError: full_name is not defined"
```

I'm getting an error. I can't understand why...??

Comment: There are no classes or private, it's functions and scope, but some smartypants decided to call it "classes" and "private / public" (It was probably Crockford, lets blame him).

Comment: It's not clear what you want. If you want "full_name" to be a function visible as a property of the prototype, then there's no reason for it to be "private".

Comment: @adeneo You're right... that's why I called it "class like" lol

Comment: see also [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Comment: @Bergi Nicely explained but it's not what I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy is using the wrong pattern for private **shared** members, the pattern is for private **instance specific** members and every instance will have it's own addressMe function.

The pattern for private shared members could wrap the prototype in an IIFE:

```
var People = function(firstName, lastName){
    // public
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;
};

(function(){
  // private shared member
  var full_name = function(){
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  };
  //privileged member that has access to private shared
  //  fullName is a closure and full_name is available
  //  in the colosure scope created for this function
  People.prototype.fullName = function(){
    //calling private member, make sure you set
    //  the invoking object (this) by using
    //  Function.prototype.call
    console.log(full_name.call(this));
    return this;
  };
}());

var person = new People('John', 'Smith');
person.fullName();
```

You can't use this pattern for instance specific private members but the function full_name is not instance specific.

A pattern for protected and more info on prototype and constructor functions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Comment: Thx for ur answer but much more for the link you attached in the end of it. Great explanation there!!! Do you share a blog of ur own as well?

Comment: @Lior Thank you, don't have a blog. Think JavaScript prototype is one of the most misunderstood things in programming and wrote that while trying to figure it out myself. SO is perfect for that as I hope comments will point out mistakes or suggest improvements.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
var full_name = function(){
    return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName;
}();
```

you're setting the variable "full_name" to be the result of *calling* that anonymous function. It's just a variable declared in the context of that constructor, however, so that doesn't really matter; nothing outside of the constructor can access it.

Thus in that prototype function, you get an error because "full_name" is in fact *not* defined. If you want the full name function on the prototype, just declare it there:

```
People.prototype.fullName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

If you want a "private" function that accessible only to code in the constructor, then you'd do something like this:

```
var People = function(firstName, lastName){
    // public
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;

    // private
    var self = this;
    function fullName(){
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName;
    }

    this.addressMe = function(msg) {
        return fullName() + ": " + msg;
    };
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var bob = new People("Bob", "Scum");
alert( bob.addressMe("stand and deliver") ); // "Bob Scum: stand and deliver"
```

Comment: you're using the wrong pattern for private shared members. The pattern you're using is for private instance specific (unique for every instance). Since full_name is a function and can be shared you don't have to ditch prototype to implement it.

Comment: @HMR I agree; I wouldn't code up anything like this, probably. The intentions of the original question are not really clear.